# How can I fix this wrong/incomplete Xen routing setup?

Tags: iptables, xen, nat

I've got some Xen hosts configured in bridged mode, whose VMs use public or private IPs:

**Host #1**

- dom0: 3.3.3.71
- dom1: 10.0.2.10
- dom2: 3.3.3.85
- dom3: 10.0.2.11

**Host #2**

- dom0: 3.3.3.72
- dom1: 3.3.3.86
- dom2: 10.0.2.12
- dom3: 10.0.2.13

**Host #3**

- dom0: 3.3.3.73
- dom1: 10.0.2.14
- dom2: 10.0.2.15
- dom3: 3.3.3.87

VMs with public IPs (3.3.3.*) are reachable from the Internet. VMs with private IPs are reachable from within each other, and this is a desired behaviour. However, they can't reach the Internet because there's no 10.0.2.1 gateway in the local subnet. How can I fix this?

One solution would be to configure one server with a 10.0.2.1 interface to act as a NAT. However I don't want any SPOF and I'd like each host to do its own NAT using the public IP address assigned to the dom0.

I believe this is just a matter of configuring iptables in the dom0's. If this is correct, how?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution. I'm still open to good alternatives and hints.

On each Xen host:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m physdev --physdev-in vif5.0 -o eth0 \
    -j SNAT --to-source 3.3.3.71
```

On each domU having a private IP (10.0.2.*):

```
route add -net 3.3.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
route add default gw 3.3.3.71
route del default gw 10.0.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you don't connect the DomUs that need access to the internet to the internet-bridges?

If you don`t want that - connect one of your DomUs that are connected to the internet to the "private" bridges and install a proxy on then (squid). Contact that proxy...

I don*t think it is a good idea to connect a Dom0 to the internet - but you will have your reasons...

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your answer. Why are you talking about Squid? I'm not running web servers. How could I "connect the DomUs that need access to the internet to the internet-bridges" as you wrote? Can you explain that better? I just wanted all the domUs to be able to access the Internet, while only a part of them being reachable from the outside with a public IP. Dom0s have to be accessible from the outside so that I can manage everything remotely.

Comment: squid is a proxy - so if you do not want to connect directly to the internet - go via that proxy. I guessed you wanted to connect to http/https services from your DomUs. As for the Bridging (you explained why you don`t want a direct access - ok): Currently you are using DomUs "single homed" - so each of the DomUs has only one network interface on one bridge. You could connect more interfaces of these DomUs to more bridges - if you like.